# howa to optimise tUniqRow and tSortRow

Tags: talend

Is it better to put tSortRow before tUniqRow or vice versa for the best perfermence ?
And how to optimize tUniqRow ?
Even if I use "disk option", the job crashes.
I'm working on a 3Million line file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to optimize your job, you can try the following:

1. Use the option "use disk" on `tSortRow` with a smaller buffer (the default 1 million rows buffer is too big, so start with a small number of rows, 50k for instance, then increase it in order to get better performance). This will use more (smaller) files on disk, so your job will run slower, but it will consume less memory.
2. Try with a `tSortRow` (using disk) and a `tAggregateSortedRow` instead of `tUniqRow` (by specifying the unique columns in the Group By section, it acts as a `tUniqRow`, the columns not part of the unique key must be specified in the Operations tab each using 'First' function). As it expects the rows to already be sorted, it doesn't sort them first in memory. Note that this component requires you to know beforehand the number of rows in your flow, which you can get from a previous subjob if you're processing your data in multiple steps.
3. Also, if the columns you're sorting by in `tSortRow` come from your database table, you can use an `ORDER BY` clause in your `tOracleInput`. This way the sorting will be done on the database side and your job won't consume memory for sort.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .

If I understood correctly, I replace tuniqrow by taggregatesoretdRow and in the params of this compose I declare the unique keys (the columns) in Group By and that's all ==> like that I can only have single lines

under job 1:
tOracleInput -> tmap-> tsort-> tFileOutputPositionnel_1 (tmp)
|OnSubjobOk
subjob 2
tFileInputPositionnel_1 (tmp) -> tMap_2-> taggregateSortedRow (instead of tuniqRow) -> tFileOutputPositionnel_2 (final)

Comment: Yes that is correct, this way you can use the global variable `(Integer)globalMap.get("tFileOutputPositional_1_NB_LINE")`  as the number of rows which is required by `tAggregateSortedRow`. Also, if the columns you're sorting by in `tSortRow` come from database, you can use an ORDER BY in your `tOracleInput` which will do the sorting on the database side, this way your job won't consume memory for sorting. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: it returns to me a file with nulls :(

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? What part of your job is not working ?

Comment: I've corrected my answer. You also need to add the columns that are not part of your unique key to tAggregateSortedRow Operations tab, and use 'First' function for each of them. Could you please try and let me know

Comment: I'm sorry, but still the null output file values :(

Comment: Which part is outputting nulls ? Is it tAggregateSortedRow ? Or another component ? you can use tLogRow to debug.